# Get Facebook post's comments using graph API by post URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I like to get comments of a post by its URL but it seems its impossible by using graph API.
From my observations, I could find these types of posts URLs:

```
https://www.facebook.com/bbwbooks/photos/a.168788885097.122872.74209335097/10153736545150098/?type=3&theater

https://www.facebook.com/4thirteengroup/posts/1285218878169361

https://www.facebook.com/groups/semsari.malezi/permalink/1159959294084128/
```

or perhaps some other types.

Is there any idea, how its possible to get comments or at least the ID of the post from the url?

Comment: What do you need it for? Just get the Post ID from the API

Comment: @WizKid I receive the url from user and then must extract all the comments. how can I get Post ID from a URL?

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

First use facebook developer section https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/1021611514583622?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Did%2Cobject_id%2Ccomments&version=v2.7

Select Application ,
Get access_token with user_posts access rights,
`me/posts?fields=id,object_id,comments` by calling this api ,you will get all posts with their comments

Comment: Then how can I get the specific post's comments? I guess it is a bad idea for getting 1 post fetch all the posts though.